# How to show a place holder block if a view is empty

Tags: views, blocks, rules

I have a site that has multiple inventory views. When a view is empty (no items to list) I need to display a block that tells the user to check back later.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Views has a feature that already accommodates this; under the **Advanced** section there is a **NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR** option that lets you add different fields on the condition there are no results in the view.

[image]

Comment: Sure. No problem. Glad to help. Make sure to mark the questions as answer.